# DIdnt work dependency_overrides in fastapi

Tags: python, python-3.x, fastapi

I am trying to write test for web service and I want to create a separate database for tests when you run them. It is my pytest fixture for realise it

```
@pytest.fixture(scope="session")
def db_engine():
    engine = create_engine(SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URL)
    if not database_exists:
        create_database(engine.url)

    Base.metadata.create_all(bind=engine)

    yield engine


@pytest.fixture(scope="function")
def db(db_engine):
    connection = db_engine.connect()
    connection.begin()
    db = Session(bind=connection)

    yield db

    db.rollback()
    connection.close()


@pytest.fixture(scope="function")
def client(db):
    app.dependency_overrides[get_db] = lambda: db

    with TestClient(app) as c:
        yield c
```

But `app.dependecy_overrides[get_db] = lambda: db` didnt work and requests continue to be sent to the main database and not the test one.
One of my endpoints

```
@router.get("/", response_model=List[RoomPayload])
def read(db: Session = Depends(get_db),
               user=Depends(manager)):

    q = db.query(Room).all()

    if not q:
        raise HTTPException(status_code=404, detail=f"Rooms not found")

    return q
```

Comment: Have you verified that your fixtures gets called when you use the client in your tests?

Comment: Yes, they called

Comment: faced the same issue, moved this code to conftest.py file and still have call to prod db instead of testing one(